# Pandas rolling window statistics calculation with input data with uneven timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-resample, pandas-rolling

**quick background:**

- this can relate to pandas `rolling`, `resample`, `asfreq`, `fillna`
- this is based on processing timeseries data so I want to use pandas `offset` (e.g., '1T', '5min', etc.) as an input to methods.
- also, I'm applying forward looking window for `rolling` method so there is this reverse of dataframe applied in the code.

**what I want to achieve:**

- basically rolling window statistics calculation and resampling done in a way shown below. In other words, **5 minute** rolling window (e.g., rolling window for 07:00 => 07:00-07:05) with **1 minute** increment of statistics (e.g., min, max, etc.) calculation.
- input data shown below

```
ts                          var1
2022-07-12 07:00:00+00:00   NaN
2022-07-12 07:01:53+00:00   1.5
2022-07-12 07:03:17+00:00   2.2
2022-07-12 07:04:02+00:00   0.9
2022-07-12 07:04:59+00:00   3.6
2022-07-12 07:05:00+00:00   NaN
2022-07-12 07:06:22+00:00   3.3
2022-07-12 07:09:46+00:00   2.3
2022-07-12 07:10:00+00:00   NaN
2022-07-12 07:11:22+00:00   1.3
2022-07-12 07:13:44+00:00   4.3
2022-07-12 07:14:26+00:00   4.1
2022-07-12 07:15:00+00:00   NaN
```

- what I want

```
ts                          var1_max    var1_min
2022-07-12 07:00:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:01:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:02:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:03:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:04:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:05:00+00:00   3.3         2.3
2022-07-12 07:06:00+00:00   3.3         2.3
2022-07-12 07:07:00+00:00   2.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:08:00+00:00   2.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:09:00+00:00   4.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:10:00+00:00   4.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:11:00+00:00   4.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:12:00+00:00   4.3         4.1
2022-07-12 07:13:00+00:00   4.3         4.1
2022-07-12 07:14:00+00:00   4.1         4.1
2022-07-12 07:15:00+00:00   NaN         NaN
```

- so far, I'm getting

```
ts                          var1_max    va1_min
2022-07-12 07:00:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:01:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:02:00+00:00   NaN         NaN
2022-07-12 07:03:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:04:00+00:00   3.6         0.9
2022-07-12 07:05:00+00:00   3.3         2.3
2022-07-12 07:06:00+00:00   3.3         2.3
2022-07-12 07:07:00+00:00   NaN         NaN
2022-07-12 07:08:00+00:00   NaN         NaN
2022-07-12 07:09:00+00:00   4.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:10:00+00:00   4.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:11:00+00:00   4.3         1.3
2022-07-12 07:12:00+00:00   NaN         NaN
2022-07-12 07:13:00+00:00   4.3         4.1
2022-07-12 07:14:00+00:00   4.1         4.1
2022-07-12 07:15:00+00:00   NaN         NaN
```

**key issues:**

- as you can see from the data that I'm getting, I can't seem to correctly fill values for those spaces with `NaN`
- basically, those `NaN` should be informed by rolling window calculation from the raw data
- I tried doing `resample` (or `asfreq`) before the rolling window calculation, but that loses some valuable information along the process when I have two values within 1 minute time frame. For example, because the input data has values of 3.6 and 0.9 between 07:04-07:05, doing resampling will not capture min (=0.9) and max (=3.6) properly at the end.

**example code:**

```
#########################################################################
# input data
data_test = [
        [
            "01:00:00",
            "01:01:53",
            "01:03:17",
            "01:04:02",
            "01:04:59",
            "01:05:00",
            "01:06:22",
            "01:09:46",
            "01:10:00",
            "01:11:22",
            "01:13:44",
            "01:14:26",
            "01:15:00"
        ],
        [np.nan, 1.5, 2.2, 0.9, 3.6, np.nan, 3.3, 2.3, np.nan, 1.3, 4.3, 4.1, np.nan]
    ]

data_test = pd.DataFrame(data_test).T
data_test.columns = ['ts', 'var1']
data_test['var1'] = data_test['var1'].astype(float)
data_test['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(data_test.ts)
data_test = data_test.set_index('ts')
    
#########################################################################
# reversing for forward looking window operation
data_test = data_test[::-1]
    
#########################################################################
# adding rolling window statistics: minimum
mins = (
    data_test.rolling(
        window="5min", 
        min_periods=1,
        closed='right'
    ).min().add_suffix("_min")
)

# adding rolling window statistics: maximum
maxs = (
    data_test.rolling(
        window="5min", 
        min_periods=1,
        closed='right'
    ).max().add_suffix("_max")
)
    
#########################################################################
# resampling with even interval
mins = mins.resample(rule="1min").min()
maxs = maxs.resample(rule="1min").max()

data_test = pd.concat([mins, maxs], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the following, where I've already converted `ts` to datetime and made it the index:

```
                           var1
ts
2022-07-12 07:00:00+00:00   NaN
2022-07-12 07:01:53+00:00   1.5
2022-07-12 07:03:17+00:00   2.2
2022-07-12 07:04:02+00:00   0.9
2022-07-12 07:04:59+00:00   3.6
2022-07-12 07:05:00+00:00   NaN
2022-07-12 07:06:22+00:00   3.3
2022-07-12 07:09:46+00:00   2.3
2022-07-12 07:10:00+00:00   NaN
2022-07-12 07:11:22+00:00   1.3
2022-07-12 07:13:44+00:00   4.3
2022-07-12 07:14:26+00:00   4.1
2022-07-12 07:15:00+00:00   NaN
```

Doing:

```
df['var1_min'] = df.resample('5min')['var1'].transform('min')
df['var1_max'] = df.resample('5min')['var1'].transform('max')
df = df.asfreq('1min', method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
                           var1  var1_min  var1_max
2022-07-12 07:00:00+00:00   NaN       0.9       3.6
2022-07-12 07:01:00+00:00   NaN       0.9       3.6
2022-07-12 07:02:00+00:00   1.5       0.9       3.6
2022-07-12 07:03:00+00:00   1.5       0.9       3.6
2022-07-12 07:04:00+00:00   2.2       0.9       3.6
2022-07-12 07:05:00+00:00   NaN       2.3       3.3
2022-07-12 07:06:00+00:00   NaN       2.3       3.3
2022-07-12 07:07:00+00:00   3.3       2.3       3.3
2022-07-12 07:08:00+00:00   3.3       2.3       3.3
2022-07-12 07:09:00+00:00   3.3       2.3       3.3
2022-07-12 07:10:00+00:00   NaN       1.3       4.3
2022-07-12 07:11:00+00:00   NaN       1.3       4.3
2022-07-12 07:12:00+00:00   1.3       1.3       4.3
2022-07-12 07:13:00+00:00   1.3       1.3       4.3
2022-07-12 07:14:00+00:00   4.3       1.3       4.3
2022-07-12 07:15:00+00:00   NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Did your `var1` column get messed up?

Comment: @jch No, not messed up, that's just what it'd look like after changing the freq to `1min` and front filling. OP could `.bfill()` that column as well if they'd like.

Comment: awesome! I haven't had a chance to use `transform` so good to be aware of the usage. BUT, if I'm looking at this right this isn't truly the "rolling" window operation.

Comment: If you compare your result versus what I want, there is a difference. For example, at 07:07 and 07:08, the var1_max should be 2.3 for both. This is because the rolling window at 07:07 becomes 07:07-07:12 and corresponding values in the input data for this window includes [2.3, NaN, 1.3], so the max of these values becomes 2.3. Similar for rolling window at 07:08, while rolling window is 07:08-07:13, values within this window is also [2.3, NaN, 1.3].

Comment: And this is exactly where I'm having trouble with with the rolling window. So appreciate the attempt! I tried replacing your `resample` with `rolling` but looks like I can't do `transform` on `rolling`. Also been reading/exploring about `agg(['min', 'max'])` thingy at the moment..

Comment: Are you actually trying to `interpolate`?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution to generate the output that I want. But unsure if this is the most elegant way. In short, it is basically (1) using `resample` and `agg` methods to resample data with respect to each statistic (`min`, `max`, `sum`, `count`) and (2) apply rolling method to each statistic again to get rolling window statistics. To calculate the rolling mean/average, I'm dividing rolling sum by rolling count.

```
#########################################################################
# resampling with agg method to retain statistics within time increment
data_resample_min = data_test.resample(rule='1min').agg(['min'])
data_resample_max = data_test.resample(rule='1min').agg(['max'])
data_resample_sum = data_test.resample(rule='1min').agg(['sum'])
data_resample_count = data_test.resample(rule='1min').agg(['count'])

#########################################################################
# reversing dataframe for forward-looking rolling window operation
data_resample_min = data_resample_min[::-1]
data_resample_max = data_resample_max[::-1]
data_resample_sum = data_resample_sum[::-1]
data_resample_count = data_resample_count[::-1]

#########################################################################
# merging multiindex column header
data_resample_min.columns = data_resample_min.columns.map('_'.join)
data_resample_max.columns = data_resample_max.columns.map('_'.join)
data_resample_sum.columns = data_resample_sum.columns.map('_'.join)
data_resample_count.columns = data_resample_count.columns.map('_'.join)
    
#########################################################################   
# adding rolling window statistics: minimum
mins = (
    data_resample_min.rolling(
        window='5min', 
        min_periods=1,
        center=False,
        closed='right'
    ).min()
)
# adding rolling window statistics: maximum
maxs = (
    data_resample_max.rolling(
        window='5min', 
        min_periods=1,
        center=False,
        closed='right'
    ).max()
)
# adding rolling window statistics: sum
sums = (
    data_resample_sum.rolling(
        window='5min', 
        min_periods=1,
        center=False,
        closed='right'
    ).sum()
)
# adding rolling window statistics: count
counts = (
    data_resample_count.rolling(
        window='5min', 
        min_periods=1,
        center=False,
        closed='right'
    ).sum() # this has to be sum for proper count calculation
)
# adding rolling window statistics: mean
means = sums.copy()
means.columns = means.columns.str.replace("_sum","_mean")
# supress/hide the warning
np.seterr(invalid='ignore')
means.loc[:, :] = sums.values/counts.values

#########################################################################
# creating summary dataframe
data_test = pd.concat([mins, maxs, means], axis=1)  
data_test = data_test[::-1]
```